# Build android error when download gradle behide proxy with VS2015

Tags: android, proxy, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

When I use VS2015 to build android, and start to download gradle, my enviroment is behide corp proxy, and I got the error as below.

Is there anyway to setup gradle proxy when download through proxy?

```
     ------ Build configuration options: --debug
    1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json""
    1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\@AppTool\android-sdk-windows
    1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
    1>  Reading build config file: C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json
    1>  Running: C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
    1>  Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
    1>
    1>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    1>  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    1>      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    1>      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    1>      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    1>      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    1>      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    1>      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    1>      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    1>      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    1>      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    1>      at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    1>      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    1>      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    1>      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    1>      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    1>      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    1>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    1>      at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    1>      ... 3 more
    1>
    1>  C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
    1>                      throw e;
    1>                      ^
    1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
    1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=C:\@temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json"
    1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: i was reference to [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/proxy-error-when-downloading-gradle-zip-during-ionic-emulate-android/31701) to setup the gradle.properties and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://services.gradle.org is unavailable for everyone right now, so your corp proxy is not the problem: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/services.gradle.org

Comment: Yeah, i was aware the gradle.org not working. Thanks anyway. :)